# Need to migrate u32 to Vec<T::AccountId>

Tags: migration, substrate-node, storage-migration

I have one storagemap which stores `u32` values, now I need to migrate this to `Vec<T::AccountId>` How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check how Substrate migrates the account references.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8221/files#diff-68096a50d12854e07693a4828590517bb81fea37a9253640278ecdc5b93b6992

The link shows you how to migrate.

And for your case:

```rs
YourMap::<T>::translate(|_key, old_u32_value|
    // This is just an example, put your `u32 -> Vec<AccountId>` logic here
    Some(vec![AccountId::from_u32(old_u32_value)])
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check [Substrate tutorial on storage migrations](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/storage-migrations/basic-storage-migration/)